# React native doesn't returns multiple components

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-native

I should develop a little app to manage sport trainings, in the main page it shows all the "trainings" stored using react-native-local-mondodb, but loading the app it doens't shows anything. Where is wrong my code?

the problem is in the "listItem" component in th middle of this code.
"start" and "mainStartNewTrainer" are links to other pages using react-native-navigator.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,   
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions} from 'react-native';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import Datastore from 'react-native-local-mongodb';

import Trainer from '../../components/Trainer/Trainer';

import startNewTraining from '../starts/startNewTraining/startNewTraining';
import startMainApp from '../starts/startMainApp/startMainApp';

let mioDB = new Datastore({filename:'mioDB',autoload:true});

class MainPage extends Component{  

    mainStartNewTrainer=()=>{
        startNewTraining();
    };
    start=()=>{
        startMainApp();
    };    
    render(){
        let addTraining=(
            <Icon 
                size={Dimensions.get('window').height<600?40:60} 
                name='add-circle-outline' 
                color='black'/>
        );
//then the component with problems

        let listItem=(
            mioDB.find({},(err,docs)=>{
                docs.map((training)=>{
                    console.log(training);                  
                    return <Trainer 
                            icon='A'
                            key={training._id} 
                            onPress={this.start} 
                            style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}} 
                            titleTrainer={training.trainingTitle}
                            />
                })
            })
        );       
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Make your choice</Text>
                <View style={styles.containerTrainers}>
                    <ScrollView horizontal={false} 
                        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer} 
                        bounces={false}>
                        <Trainer 
                            onPress={this.mainStartNewTrainer} 
                            icon={addTraining} 
                            titleTrainer='Add new training'/>
                        {listItem}
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        alignItems:'center',
        backgroundColor:'#8D0C42',
        height:'100%',
        justifyContent:'flex-start',
        width:'100%',
    },
    containerTrainers:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        width:'90%',
    },
    scrollContainer:{              
        flexWrap:'wrap',
        width:'100%',
    },
    title:{
        color:'black',
        fontFamily:'Aclonica',
        fontSize:Dimensions.get('window').height<600?20:35,
        marginBottom:'3%',
        marginTop:'3%',
        maxWidth:'80%',
        textAlign:'justify',
    },
});
export default MainPage;
```

Excuse me for my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not assigning a value to `listItem`, it's always null, therefore nothing gets rendered.

I'd recommend you to use the `state` to keep your data and then render whatever is in there. For example:

```
class MainPage extends Component{  

    state = {
      list: [], // Initialize the state with an empty list
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      mioDB.find({},(err,docs)=>{
         // Update the state with values saved
         this.setState({ list: docs });
      });
    }

    mainStartNewTrainer=()=>{
        startNewTraining();
    };
    start=()=>{
        startMainApp();
    };    
    render(){
        let addTraining=(
            <Icon 
                size={Dimensions.get('window').height<600?40:60} 
                name='add-circle-outline' 
                color='black'/>
        );

        // Render items in the state
        let listItem= this.state.list.map((training)=>{
                    console.log(training);                  
                    return <Trainer 
                            icon='A'
                            key={training._id} 
                            onPress={this.start} 
                            style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}} 
                            titleTrainer={training.trainingTitle}
                            />
                })
            });

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Make your choice</Text>
                <View style={styles.containerTrainers}>
                    <ScrollView horizontal={false} 
                        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer} 
                        bounces={false}>
                        <Trainer 
                            onPress={this.mainStartNewTrainer} 
                            icon={addTraining} 
                            titleTrainer='Add new training'/>
                        {listItem}
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't works, I'm using redux also; the state in this component doesn't do problems if this isn't connect to redux,do you?

Comment: You never mentioned redux in your original post. If you are using redux, then you should have your data in the store, using the `connect` method, you can access that data and give it to the props, then in then in the render method you should use it in a similar way I did in this answer.